# using jquery not() selector in Cufon

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon

I am using Cufon to replace some list items in a nav. There is some content inside a div element (which is inside the list item) that I dont want replaced.  I was hoping this would work...

```
Cufon.replace('li:not("li div")');
```

But it doesn't.

I realize that if the exclusion applied to a sibling I could use something like...

```
Cufon.replace('li:not(li.dontreplace)');
```

But i want to exclude a div which is a CHILD of the LI

Can someone help please?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
Cufon.replace("li:not(:has(div))");
```

Comment: Hey Frederic,
Thanks for that. It was close, but not quite what I was after. I wanted to replace the most of the LI but NOT the DIV portion.  I have now figured out how to do it.